# List Of Cisco IOS Devices

Tags: cisco, router, ios

I want to start playing a bit with Cisco IOS and I have a Cisco WAP200 Wireless Router here, so I want to know if it comes with IOS and also where I can find a list of the IOS devices so I can know the other devices that run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your router doesn't run IOS at all, in fact it's not really a true Cisco device, it's a rebadged Linksys one.

I'm not aware of a single list of all IOS capable devices but certainly all their 7-series routers and Catalyst switches can run one version of IOS. But the real problem you face is that IOS is seriously old now, there was code called IOS in the early 90's that won't run on anything made today and vice versa, today's code won't run on the old stuff. In fact there's so many different 'strains' of IOS it's actually very complex just keeping track of it all.

Now all you really want is an IOS emulator, there are lots of these for all sorts of platforms (just google 'ios emulator'), most people going for CCNA or similar start using these while they familiarise themselves with the actual hardware, often then going to places like ebay and craigslist to pickup workable but older 'proper' IOS devices such as old Cat 3750's or small routers.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco 2600 routers are generally the 'mother of all labs/testing'. They can run a very recent version of IOS (12.4) if you load it up with memory and can be found very cheaply on Ebay.
3600 or 3725's are other good models that can be found cheap on Ebay.

On the switching side one of the best value for money lab switches is the Catalyst 3550, it can do layer 3 and is pretty versatile. 
It's no longer suitable in a "proper" CCIE lab's (3560 has taken it's place, mostly because of changes to QoS management in 3560) so the price of 3550 on Ebay is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

[Cisco feature navigator](http://cisco.com/go/fn) contains the list of all IOS/IOS-XE/IOS-XR/CatOS devices.

[This list](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/Dispatch?act=rlsSelect&task=search&searchby=platform) is not easy to re-use by hand (drop-down menu), but the document's source should be easy to parse.